# Multiple instances of countdown into html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, momentjs, countdown

I'm working a countdown with moment js.
This is the code:
https://telegra.ph/Codepen---Code-06-22 (CodePen)

I use this code to integrate into a programming table.
This is the table:
https://telegra.ph/Codepen---Code-06-22 (CodePen)

Now.
What I really want to achieve is:

First. Have a separate code for each row in my table.
(Perhaps one game is scheduled for 10:00, but another game could be scheduled for 10:15).

Second. Change the "if" condition so that the text displayed by my div changes if it has been more than 2 hours (which is what the games last approximately).

I am new to this so I appreciate any help.

Thanks-

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your question belongs directly into your question, in text form & properly formatted - not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: Sorry, I had a lot of trouble publishing my code directly, I will be reading the articles that will help me write well in the future.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a two-step function:

- The outer function will identify a DOM element into which the countdown will be written. The argument to this function must be a valid CSS selector.
- The inner one will actually start the countdown to a given date. The argument(s) to this function will be passed on to the `new Date()` constructor called internally.

The below snippet is merely a demonstration of the mechanics needed for such a reusable function. My outer function will also provide a "stop" button to make the countdown stop. Within each outer function you will have access to the `setInterval()`-handle `t`. You can utilise this to program any other stop-mechanism for it (involving `clearInterval(t)`).

I was lazy when programming the time string inside the inner function: It will work correctly as long as the target event is within 31 days in the future from the current datetime. If you want to use it for a more general case you will have to put a little more effort into it ...

```js
function countdown(DOMsel){
  let trgEL=document.querySelector(DOMsel);   // target DOM element
  if (trgEL) return function(){
    let trgDT=new Date(...arguments),         // target Date object
        btn=trgEL.nextElementSibling;         // STOP button
    let t=setInterval(function(){
         let now=new Date()
         if (trgDT-now<0) { 
           trgEL.innerHTML="<b>Game over, please insert coin!</b>";
           clearInterval(t); // stop the current countdown
         } else {
           let str=new Date(trgDT - now).toJSON(); // timer string
           trgEL.textContent=+str.substr(8,2)-1+':'+str.substr(11,8)
         }
         }, 1000);
    btn.innerHTML='<button> stop </button>';  // build stop button ...
    btn.onclick=function(){clearInterval(t);} // assign stop function to it
  } 
  else return function(){console.log('target DOM element not found.');};
}
var now=new Date();
countdown('td:nth-child(3)')(now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds()+20));
countdown('tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(3)')(2020,5,26,20,5,27);
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>some</td><td>target1</td><td>next cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>table</td><td>with</td><td>various</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>cells</td><td>in</td><td>it.</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>d</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>e</td><td>target2</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>f</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>g</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>h</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

I used the `new Date()` constructor in the format `(y,mon,d,min,sec)` with `mon` being a 0-based index of months, therefore `5` indicates the 6th month: June. Interestingly, the `d` numbers work like normal calendar dates. But they may overshoot: if I had entered 31, then that would have become "1 July". Other formats are available, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date). Your input is always interpreted according to your local time zone, but the string we get from `.toJSON()` is always "Greenwich time". This seems weird at first, but is a great help when you are dealing with a global audience as they will all refer to the same clock automatically!

**Edit:**

I changed the target datetime of my first countdown such that it will always give you a 20 seconds window. After that a final message appears and he countdown stops.

Comment: Magnificent.
Thanks for helping.
I just have a question.
How do the dates work?

countdown('td:nth-child(3)')(2020,5,22,19,5);
countdown('tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(3)')(2020,5,23,20,5,27);

If for example i want the counter to end June 23, 2020 at 12 noon

Comment: And what date is it taking?

I need it to be a universal time, I mean.
If a person from the USA enters the site, they must watch the same time as another person who enters from Spain

Comment: Please see my updated answer for further explanation.

Comment: Sorry for insisting, but when testing I can't understand how it works.

I take as a reference: June 25, 2020 at 11:30 am, but the result is (30: 12: 01: 29), however the result should be: 0d, 12h, 5m at the time of the test.
I'm just modifying: countdown ('tr: nth-child (5) td: nth-child (3)') (2020,6,25,11,30,00);
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the JavaScript `Date ()` constructor the second argument (the month) is a zero based index. Therefore the index 6 refers to July not June.

Comment: I already understood.
Many thanks.
My code already works. I owe you millions, haha!

Comment: To finish.
Is there any way that when the counter reaches 0 it will print a text on the screen?

For example: The event started at 00:00 and it is 00:00, so instead of starting again, it shows something like: Started

Comment: There is! Have a look at my changed snippet.

Comment: It's AMAZING!
What if in the future you want that after a few hours after the counter reaches 0, it shows something else?

For example, my event starts at 00:00 and ends at 02:00, so when the counter arrived at 00:00 my cell displays: Game over, please insert coin!

How to make it show up at 02:00: Game over, over, please insert coin !?

Comment: Well, I think it is about time you picked up the ball and bounced it yourself! You could change my code such, that when the condition `trgDT-now<0` was met you did *not* call `clearInterval(t)` yet but add another `else if (trgDT-now< -twoHoursInMs)` condition with the second message and end the interval action then ...

Comment: I think I have succeeded!
I have added this code:
`if (trgDT-now< -7200000){
            trgEL.innerHTML="<b>Ended!</b>";
        }`
right after yours:

`if (trgDT-now<0) { 
           trgEL.innerHTML="<b>Live!</b>";`

Here is a screenshot of the code.

It's well done?

[Screenshoot](https://i.ibb.co/yymrypP/code.jpg)

Comment: :D Glad you found your solution!